# Graph database conversion into relational database

Tags: neo4j, relational-database, rdbms

I have already created a web application based on a graph database. I am wondering if there is a possibility to convert the graph database into a relational database.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Why not just create relational database instead then?
If you already have data in your graph data base you will need to write custom code to transform the data in the relational db format. There is not automatic way to do that.

Comment: Thank you Jeroen :) I need to think of transforming this into the relational database because I have already written it in neo4j and the whole application is based on it, but then my supervisor wants to make the database relational to make it accessible for another application based on the relational database..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you are using Neo4j since your question has the Neo4j tag.

If you are wanting to export data from Neo4j into a relational database you might want to consider using CSV files as an intermediate step as many relational databases have CSV import tooling. I've used the [neo4j-shell tools extension](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#export) for this purpose in the past. Also, [here](http://neo4j.com/blog/export-csv-from-neo4j-curl-cypher-jq/) is a recent blog post about exporting data from Neo4j to CSV format.

Comment: Thank you very much William :) I will check those options.

Answer (score 0):

Converting a graph database to a relational database is possible but complex. It involves mapping graph data to tables while maintaining data integrity. Consider the trade-offs in data modeling and query efficiency before proceeding with the conversion.
I hope this helps.